# Problem with setCursorPos in Flash - Away3D

Tags: flash, actionscript, away3d

I'm making a 1st person shooter for Flash in Away3D, but it seems that setCursorPos isn't working properly. When I call setCursorPos, the cursor moves to the center of the screen, but also triggers a MOUSE_MOVE event. Is this expected behavior? How do I know when the MOUSE_MOVE event is caused by the setCursorPos; or whether it's caused by actual mouse movement? Here is a code sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
private function onMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {
if (prevY == 0) {
                    prevY = evt.stageY;
                    prevX = evt.stageX;
                }
                    mainView.camera.rotate(Vector3D.X_AXIS,evt.stageY - prevY);

                }
            }
            //This triggers a MOUSE_MOVE event, causing this function to be called again.
                nativeInterface.setCursorPos(nativeInterface.screenResolution[0] / 2, nativeInterface.screenResolution[1] / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with nativeInterface and setCursorPos. Could you give a few more details ? Is this Away3D or Away3DLite ?

The first thing that comes to mind to separate the two is checking the [eventPhase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#eventPhase) and doing and if statement based on that, if the eventPhase is different depending when/what triggers the event.

HTH

Comment: This is Away3D (not Away3D lite). I'm using the most recent SVN update.

Comment: @IDWMaster If your using a sample, could you please post a link to it, or post a basic document class I could easily test/debug ?

Comment: The nativeInterface class is a plugin that was uploaded to the social desktop plugin gallery:
http://elcnet.servehttp.com/startcontent/plugins.aspx
The plugin modifies something about Flash player's behavior, and I'm not quite sure how it works or where I can get the source for it.

Comment: The installer also asked for the installation path for my Flex IDE directory for some reason. It's a plugin that allows for access to native operating system features from within Flash player. The plugin must also be installed by end-users in order to play such Flash videos.

Comment: @IDWMaster Sorry, but I am not familiar with this IDW As far as I can tell this library has a lower level access to the system and have native control over the cursor position ? I find this a bit strange. The way you describe it, sounds like a browser plugin that wraps swf files and has an api to for swf/plugin communication. Do people actually install this plugin ? A plugin running a plugin ? For a 1st person shooter, why not use something like Unity with it's WebPlayer until Molehill and Away3D/Alternativa3D get released ?

Comment: I'm not exactly how it works, but right now the IDW Social Desktop system is in a closed beta stage. Our company sent out a few copies of the software that people can use to test, and develop plugins to contribute to the marketplace. The goal is to create a cross-platform standard for creating content-rich websites using Java, Silverlight, Flash, and HTML5 that integrate with the native operating system. This plugin was just something that a beta tester contributed to the project, and I thought it was quite interesting, even though I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: My company is planning to transition to Molehill on its release date. I don't know whether it wraps Flash in its own plugin, or if it somehow injects a script into the Flash process, but it does show a security message box asking for native interop privileges when a script using the plugin executes.

Comment: This solution worked when I updated to the most recent version of IDW Social Desktop. It was apparently a bug with an older version. Thanks!